# Multi-Document TOC showing in wrong order

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, table-of-contents

I had a large document that was having formatting issues, so I split it into 2 files.  Chapters 1-7 are in the main doc with the TOC and a second doc has chapters 8-12.

I have the following:

```
{TOC \O "1-3" \H \Z \U}
{RD \f "MCDPS Training Manual Part2.docx"}
```

The TOC is created and has entries from both documents, however its showing the entries from Chapter 8-11 first and then Chapter 1-7.  I've read that it should list them based on page numbers, but its not.  Chapter 8 starts at page 121, yet its listing it first.

How can I get it to show the TOC from the main doc first and then the RD?

Answer (score 0):

Page numbering is included from the ordering as it appears in the Word document (top down), the same goes for RD fields I can only assume.

Therefore you need to put the RD field at the end of the document so it will appear after the entries in the main document body.